# SharePoint 2010 InfoPath Web Part Query from Query String Web Part

Tags: 2010, web-part, infopath, query-string

I have been wracking my brain, Google, blogs, etc. for an answer to my problem for about the last day and finally gave in to ask the question. I'm fairly new to InfoPath, but less new to SharePoint. I'll start by describing what I'm trying to do.

I am attempting to create a SharePoint list that will automatically flip a Boolean (Yes/No) if the item is accessed through a New Item form or an Edit/Display Item form. Essentially a "unread/read" value. I thought I had found my solution, but it isn't working the way I thought it would.

My thoughts were to create an InfoPath form to replace the default SharePoint list input. I created a new column in the SharePoint list to allow a value to be fed into it, then edited the Content Type Form under Form Web Parts and added a Query String (URL) Filter web part that fed into the InfoPath Form Web Part. The New Item and Edit/Display Items send different values to differentiate which form it's open in.

The values were fed into the form and they appear on the web part in SharePoint, but whenever I try to do any conditional statements in the InfoPath Form Load rules (or any other control's rules) on the input value, it's as if InfoPath cannot see the value. This is true for either the data field or query field. I have tried a rule based submit on the form after loading to try to get the info into SharePoint so I can work off the data that way, but submitting does not do anything either.

I will also add that I do not SharePoint designer capability as my company does not allow its use.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create different views for new, edit and view in Infopath form.
- Create a column lets say '`status`', whose default value is '`Unread`'

In InfoPath designer,

> data tab, Form Load rules, add action 'set a fields value' to 'Read' for status column. (`for only 'edit' and 'view' views, not for New`).

So, whenever the item is viewed or edited, it will have an update to read.

In UI, you have to update New Form to use NewView, Edit Form to use EditView etc., by editing form web parts (`List tools -> List -> Customize List`)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see what you're saying about giving each view in SharePoint a corresponding view in InfoPath. I had the same idea previously, but as far as I knew, the Form Load rules apply to all InfoPath views. I looked, but I couldn't find a way to restrict which rules apply to which view. How do you go about setting Form Load rules to apply to only certain views?

Comment: Right, load rules apply to all the views. You can distinguish New view to an Edit View using conditions like for example, ID is Blank/Not Blank.
But this is applicable only for New and Edit. 
Since we cannot submit the data in Display Form, you can use CEWP in the display form page to submit the data.
Refer this URL for CEWP Script 
https://nishantrana.me/2013/10/22/implementing-marking-item-as-read-functionality-for-list-item-in-sharepoint-2013/